# Issue creating data pump export job from sqldeveloper

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, database-administration, oracle-xe

I am trying to create data pump export using oracle sql developer wizard below are the grants provided to the user from which I am trying to setup data pump export

```
grant create session, create table, create procedure, exp_full_database, imp_full_database to TESTE;
grant read, write on directory DOCUMENTS to TESTE;
grant read, write on directory DATA_PUMP_DIR to TESTE;
```

but after completing wizard i get below error

```
...
 END IF;
EXCEPTION 
WHEN OTHERS THEN 
    NULL;
END;
dbms_output.put_line('REMOVE FINAL TRACE TEXT');
 Raise;
END;
Error report -
ORA-31626: job does not exist
ORA-06512: at line 77
31626. 00000 -  "job does not exist"
*Cause:    An invalid reference to a job which is no longer executing,
       is not executing on the instance where the operation was
       attempted, or that does not have a valid Master Table.
       Refer to any following error messages for clarification.
*Action:   Start a new job, or attach to an existing job that has a
       valid Master Table.
```

here is the plsql code generated by wizard at the end

```
set scan off
set serveroutput on
set escape off
whenever sqlerror exit 
DECLARE
h1 number;
errorvarchar varchar2(100):= 'ERROR';
tryGetStatus number := 0;
begin
    h1 := dbms_datapump.open (operation => 'EXPORT', job_mode => 'SCHEMA',             job_name => 'EXPORT_JOB_SQLDEV_944', version => 'COMPATIBLE'); 
tryGetStatus := 1;
dbms_datapump.set_parallel(handle => h1, degree => 1); 
dbms_datapump.add_file(handle => h1, filename => 'EXPDAT-'||to_char(sysdate,'yyyy-mm-dd-hh24_mi_ss')||'.LOG', directory => 'DATA_PUMP_DIR', filetype => 3); 
dbms_datapump.set_parameter(handle => h1, name => 'KEEP_MASTER', value => 1); 
dbms_datapump.metadata_filter(handle => h1, name => 'SCHEMA_EXPR', value => 'IN(''MERCHANDISER'')'); 
dbms_datapump.add_file(handle => h1, filename => 'EXPDAT%U-'||to_char(sysdate,'yyyy-mm-dd-hh24_mi_ss')||'.DMP', directory => 'DATA_PUMP_DIR', filesize => '100M',  filetype => 1); 
dbms_datapump.set_parameter(handle => h1, name => 'INCLUDE_METADATA', value => 1); 
dbms_datapump.set_parameter(handle => h1, name => 'DATA_ACCESS_METHOD', value => 'AUTOMATIC'); 
dbms_datapump.set_parameter(handle => h1, name => 'ESTIMATE', value => 'BLOCKS'); 
dbms_datapump.start_job(handle => h1, skip_current => 0, abort_step => 0); 
dbms_datapump.detach(handle => h1); 
errorvarchar := 'NO_ERROR'; 
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
BEGIN 
    IF ((errorvarchar = 'ERROR')AND(tryGetStatus=1)) THEN 
        DBMS_DATAPUMP.DETACH(h1);
    END IF;
EXCEPTION 
WHEN OTHERS THEN 
    NULL;
END;
RAISE;
END;
/
```

I have also tried below command in bash

```
expdp TESTE/TESTEr@localhost schemas=TESTE directory=documents dumpfile=test.dmp logfile=test.log
```

and got below error

```
Connected to: Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
ORA-31626: job does not exist
ORA-31637: cannot create job SYS_EXPORT_SCHEMA_06 for user MERCHANDISER
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SYS_ERROR", line 95
ORA-06512: at "SYS.KUPV$FT_INT", line 798
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00331: illegal reference to SYS.SYS
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

any idea what is causing issue

Comment: Can you check this parameter STREAMS_POOL_SIZE with this command --> show parameter STREAMS_POOL_SIZE

Comment: @ivanzg Thank you for the response I checked using the command and value for Streams_POOL_SIZE is 0, I am doing same thing on another installation of oracle and that installation also have 0 value for STREAMS_POOL_SIZE and it does not show any error there

Comment: @ivanzg I used these commands to alter values of system variables `alter system set pga_aggregate_target=140M ; alter system set sga_target=500M ; alter system set STREAMS_POOL_SIZE=400; show parameter STREAMS_POOL_SIZE;` and now I am getting only error **ORA-31626: job does not exist**

Comment: Please check this parameter also "aq_tm_processes" it should not be 0.

Comment: Also, please try to put parameter "job_name" of function "dbms_datapump.open" to null instead of giving a explicit value.

Comment: @ivanzg Tried changing aq_tm_processes from 0 to 5, and also tried job_name null, still job does not exist error. Since there are lots of job now because of lots of tries I have done I tried to remove master tables created for these jobs but unable to drop them, also I am even unable to drop any schemas as well, with error  **ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1**

Comment: Can you run the block again and check the alert log of the database to see if some errors pop out for this.

Comment: @ivanzg Tried everything again but nothing is popping up in **/u01/app/oracle/diag/rdbms/xe/XE/trace/alert_XE.log**  ,   I just clean installed everything and it is working but I would really like to know what happened, I still have a backup copy of the OS with issue if you would like me try out any other thing that comes to your mind

Comment: Having the same issue on XE database. Just made 3 jobs and next attempts to call wizard end with this

Comment: Error is gone after deleting existing job master tables. It seems XE has some limit on amount of jobs, whatever..

Answer (score 0):

Database Permission issue.

At least that is what I discovered after 2 days.

Comment: What permissions fixed it? They start with the permissions they used. What are they missing?

Comment: @JeremyCaney Two things. 1 issue was a permission issue. Currently it is set to grant all, which is overkill. 2. The datapump storeprocedure had to be modified because it was based on expecting a full dump but in reality we were only being given some of the tables so the SP had to be modified. Still working through and testing things out.